# Add properties to Neo4j Dynamically

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to add a new property dynamically  to an existing node ? Here I wan to assign both key and value dynamically to my chypher query.. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a map with key value pairs and add the pairs with `SET`.

Example 1: Add properties, will erase the others

```
WITH {name:"Kenny", age:10} as kv
MATCH (n:Person {uid:"123-fff"}) SET n = kv
```

Example 2: Append properties, will replace values of existing keys :

```
WITH {name:"Kenny", age:10} as kv
MATCH (n:Person {uid:"123-fff"}) SET n += kv
```

Ideally you would pass the kv's as query parameters, so the json sent for the query would be something like this :

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "MATCH (n:Person) SET n += {kv}",
      "params": {
        "kv": {
          "name": "kenny",
          "age": 10
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My scenario is , I'm  migrating data from RDBMS to Neo4j. I have my data set in 2 Csv files. First datset creates nodes and second dataset has some more properties and those properties should be added to existing nodes ...

Comment: This shouldn't be any problem, can you post maybe 2 or 3 lines of your csv so I can see how the properties should be mapped in the Cypher query ?

Comment: "Name"," Value","mo_I'd" \n Country,US,678 \n country,Canada,2234 \n country,India,4536

Comment: Pleas consider \n as new line.. I'm not able to paste it proper format since I'm using stack overflow app.. My apologies for tis inconvenience..

Comment: I would like to add above cvs data into existing employee node which is created from dataset1.

Comment: So the Country is a property right ? How can you retrieve the Employee nodes ?

Comment: Yes country is property... I will retrieve employee node based on mo_id... I want tis name and value combination should be update as a new property  to existing nodes based  on mo_id.

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible to have dynamic property keys. You can achieve this by importing the data with your programming language then. Except if all lines "name" value will be country

Comment: Yeah. I should try it with java program.. Thanks for your valuable inputs