# Formatting RETURN in neo4j: grouping by an item

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use the following cypher to get all the entities of the label User:

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) 
WITH u,r,m
RETURN u.id as uid, m.id as mid, r.rating as rating
```

This returns me an array of objects formatted as:

```
[
    {
      "uid": "user1",
      "mid": "bettercallsaul",
      "rating": 9
    },
    {
      "uid": "user1",
      "mid": "breakingbad",
      "rating": 10
    }
    // ... etc
]
```

I would like however to group it by the `u.id` (or `uid`) such that it returns something like (or similar):

```
[
   {"user1": 
       {"mid": "bettercallsaul", "rating": 9},
       {"mid": "breakingbad", "rating": 10},
       // ... etc
   },
   {"user2":
       {"mid": "breakingbad", "rating": 7},
       {"mid": "bettercallsaul", "rating": 8},
       // ... etc
   }
   // ... etc
]
```

Comment: These are related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622805/cypher-query-with-literal-map-syntax-dynamic-keys, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290523/add-properties-to-neo4j-dynamically. Using plain Cypher, you cannot dynamically assign keys to a map (e.g. "user1" in your example). You can either use "pair"-like lists or [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for for the COLLECT() function.

Maybe try this query:

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) 
RETURN u.id,COLLECT({mid:m.id, rating:r.rating}) as movieRatings
```

If you're using Neo4j 3.1.x or higher, you can use pattern comprehension and map projection to make this easier:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u.id as user, 
  [(u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) | m {.id, rating:r.rating}] as movieRatings
```

And if you want the list of movieRatings to be a part of each user's properties map, you can use map projection to do this too:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u {.id, .name, movieRatings:
  [(u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) | m {.id, rating:r.rating}] } as user
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is completely possible to do what you want.
However I think you will get close with the [collect function](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/aggregation/#aggregation-collect) of Neo.

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie) 
WITH u.id as uid, m.id as mid, r.rating as rating
RETURN uid, collect([mid, rating])
```